# Solving coupled differential equations of second order using Euler's method

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve the following differential equations numerically using Euler's Method.

$\qquad \frac{d^2s_x}{dt^2}= \frac{dv_x}{dt} = -kv_x\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$

$\qquad \frac{d^2s_y}{dt^2}= \frac{dv_y}{dt} = g-kv_y\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$

Comment: But the links you are referring to is programming. I want a mathematical solution by hand.

Comment: `But the links you are referring to is programming` Then you are on the wrong site. Please check the Mathematics web site, this is the Mathematica web site (with an `a` at the end). This site is about programming using Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see  a very clearly.